# container div way bigger

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
        </div>
        <div class="content1">
        </div>
        <div class="content2">
        </div>
        <div class="content3">
        </div>
        <div class="content4">
        </div>
        <div class="subcontent">
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    background:#25523B;
    }
    
    .main { 
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 5; 
        background-color: #77dd76;
        color:white;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .content1 { 
        grid-area: 2 / 1 / 6 / 2;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 2px solid #73AD21;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;

    }
    .content2 { 
        grid-area: 2 / 2 / 6 / 3; 
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 2px solid #73AD21;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    .content3 { 
        grid-area: 2 / 3 / 6 / 4; 
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 2px solid #73AD21;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px; 
    }
    .content4 { 
        grid-area: 2 / 4 / 6 / 5; 
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 2px solid #73AD21;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    .subcontent {
        grid-area: 6 / 1 / 7 / 5; 
        background-color: #77dd76;
        border-radius: 25px;
        }
    .footer { 
        grid-area: 7 / 1 / 8 / 5;
        background-color: #77dd76;
        color:white;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 10px;
        
     }

    table {
        font-family: Georgia, serif;
        border: 6px solid white;
        background-color: #D4EED1;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
      }
```

So the problem with this css is that my container div seems way bigger than my other div. So i would like to know if there is a way on how to keep the same div ratio between the other div so that it stays within the container div but must be filled.
As of now the other div are not going full screen even when the container div is.

Comment: *my container div seems way bigger than my other div* both of which you fail to show. How on earth are you hoping for any help without providing the essential information? You want us to guess your markup structure based on your CSS?

Comment: i am super sorry i will upload my html file too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change `grid-template-column : repeat(4,1fr)` or you can delete this `grid-template-column`
I have tried and it works

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    background:#25523B;
    }
    
    .main { 
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 5; 
        background-color: #77dd76;
        color:white;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .content1 { 
        grid-area: 2 / 1 / 6 / 2;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 2px solid #73AD21;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;

    }
    .content2 { 
        grid-area: 2 / 2 / 6 / 3; 
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 2px solid #73AD21;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    .content3 { 
        grid-area: 2 / 3 / 6 / 4; 
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 2px solid #73AD21;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px; 
    }
    .content4 { 
        grid-area: 2 / 4 / 6 / 5; 
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 2px solid #73AD21;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    .subcontent {
        grid-area: 6 / 1 / 7 / 5; 
        background-color: #77dd76;
        border-radius: 25px;
        }
    .footer { 
        grid-area: 7 / 1 / 8 / 5;
        background-color: #77dd76;
        color:white;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 10px;
        
     }

    table {
        font-family: Georgia, serif;
        border: 6px solid white;
        background-color: #D4EED1;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
      }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
        </div>
        <div class="content1">
        </div>
        <div class="content2">
        </div>
        <div class="content3">
        </div>
        <div class="content4">
        </div>
        <div class="subcontent">
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help it works. and i would just also like to ask you something more. how can i keep the gap between my content divisions constant. the gap between them seems to be getting bigger when in full screen more. no matter what the screen size i would like to be like 10px if possible.

Comment: first you can resolve this answer so that others know too

Comment: try to make the width content auto, to maintain the gap between them

Comment: `width : auto;`